# Logo size should not reduce after uploading - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I have had uploaded a logo in my site.

After uploading the image's size is reduced. Because of that, image quality is decreased and it doesn't look good.

What should I need to do **TO NOT REDUCE THE SIZE OF THE LOGO** after uploading.

I'm uploading via `admin/appearance/settings/theme_name` and using **"Upload logo image"** option

In admin/config/media/image-toolkit the JPEG quality is 75%. I made it 100%, still it doesn't work.

Any suggestions or advices will be helpful...

Comment: Does it happen on other themes as well?

Comment: Icon means favicon which will be tiny 16x16 px. Don't use that, use the logo field instead.

Comment: @KariKääriäinen [Not really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#HTML5_recommendation_for_icons_in_multiple_sizes) for the size. With using dedicated field I agree.

Comment: @@Molot: No.. I didn't check for the other themes... Is that a drupal issue or theme related issue ??

Comment: Which theme do you have?

Comment: @@Kari: http://www.devsaran.com/drupal-theme/responsive-blog

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "Upload icon image", that's for favicon. Use "Logo image settings" -> "Upload **logo** image".

I tested this theme and both logo and favicon work perfectly. Logo is not altered in any way and favicon works, no matter what size.

Comment: I given the info wrongly... It is "Upload logo image" only...

Comment: OK. Anyway, I wasn't able to reproduce this. I think you should contact the creator of this theme.